# Proving $ \sin{x} - \sin{y} = \sin{(x - y)} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos{(x + y)}} {1 + \cos{(x - y)}}} $

Tags: trigonometry

I want to prove following trig identity:

$$
\sin{x} - \sin{y} = \sin{(x - y)} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos{(x + y)}}  {1 + \cos{(x - y)}}}
$$

for

$$ 0 < x < \pi, 0 < y < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

What would be a strategy to do this? Squaring both sides and using the regular addition/subtraction identities doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that $1 + \cos\theta = 2\cos^2\frac\theta{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You will need that
$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$
$$\sin(x-y)=2\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$
and $$\cos(x+y)=2\cos^2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)-1$$
$$\cos(x-y)=2\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)-1$$

Comment: Oh wow. I knew the bottom two identities, but not the two upper ones. Thanks!

Comment: I hope, you can solve your problem now!

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\sin x-\sin y}{\sin(x-y)}=\dfrac{2\sin(x-y)/2\cos(x+y)/2}{2\sin(x-y)/2\cos(x-y)/2}$$

We have $-\dfrac\pi2<(x\pm y)/2<\dfrac\pi2$

Use $\cos2z=2\cos^2z-1$

$\implies\cos z=+\sqrt{?}$